# Error while saving large Spark Dataframe to Hive table on Databricks

Tags: pyspark, jdbc, hive, databricks

I'm trying to save spark dataframe as table in Databricks. The size of df is around 7GB.

`df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("A","B","C").saveAsTable(f"{schema}.{table}")`

I'm getting this error message:

> Caused by: shaded.com.databricks.client.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Databricks]JDBCDriver The file XXXX has not been downloaded successfully and the driver will not retry due to exceeding of the max retry limit 10, you can increase the max retry limit by setting MaxConsecutiveResultFileDownloadRetries.

What steps should I try to solve the issue?
The size of cluster I'm using is multi node DS4.
[image]